# DecimalFormat returns wrong result

Tags: java, android, math, decimalformat

Anybody know what I have done wrong here? I got a float number, let say it is 0.04. After the format, it turns to 0.03. Apparently the output result is already 0.01 lower than the input.

Here is my code:

```
float creditAvailableProportion = this.accountSummary != null ? (this.accountSummary.getCreditAvailable()/this.accountSummary.getCreditLimit()) : 0;
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat =  new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
        float formattedCreditAvailableProportion = Float.parseFloat(decimalFormat.format(creditAvailableProportion));

        return Math.min(1.0f, formattedCreditAvailableProportion);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(0.04));` prints `0.04`; you are calling it with some value less than `0.04` (which will be *floored* to `0.03`).

Comment: @Long Can you please show us what the values of `this.accountSummary.getCreditAvailable()` and `this.accountSummary.getCreditLimit()` are that make you expect that dividing them is 0.04?

Comment: Don't format it. Just round it to 2 decimals. You should be okay.

Comment: Do a System.out.println(creditAvailableProportion).  You should find it is less that .04 before the formatting.

Comment: But I need it to be in that format. Is there any way to get the right value? I tried both Floor and Ceiling but none of them are correct.

Answer (score 2):

As no one has explained the issue, let me briefly explain what's happening. Floating numbers in most systems, including java, are not exact. That means .04, internally is stored for example as .03999999999 or .040000001 or something similar. Therefore when you format it with the floor format, you may end up with .03.
The solution is to use rounding format, or add .0000001 to the value before format. That way even floor will get it right.
Another way, is to dump floating numbers entirely, if possible, and use integers (like 1e6), similar to what Android does with geo coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

How to debug this:

Run this code, it should make your problem clear:

```
float creditAvailableProportion = this.accountSummary != null ? (this.accountSummary.getCreditAvailable()/this.accountSummary.getCreditLimit()) : 0;
System.out.println(creditAvailableProportion)              //Original value
DecimalFormat decimalFormat =  new DecimalFormat("#.##");
decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
String temp = decimalFormat.format(creditAvailableProportion);
System.out.println(temp);                                      //formatted string
float formattedCreditAvailableProportion = Float.parseFloat(decimalFormat.format(creditAvailableProportion));
System.out.println(formattedCreditAvailableProportion);         //Parsed float.

return Math.min(1.0f, formattedCreditAvailableProportion);
```

Hopefully, this will teach you to fish a bit.

Comment: I think it is because of this one but unsure why: decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);

Comment: Well, which value was the first value that did not have the correct number?  With my code you should get three values printed out.  What were they?

Comment: Please, include the output from all three printouts.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try Math.floor().   No use turning it into a string and what not.

```
float temp = 7.888888f;
temp = temp * 100;
        temp = (float) Math.floor((double)temp);
        temp = temp /100;
        System.out.println(temp);
```